# DELETE Trigger that does not allow DELETE row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Is there a way that I can create a trigger in SQL Server that does not allow delete to happen?

For instance, I have a table `Customers` where `CustomerId` is the primary key.
Assuming I am in Query Analyzer and by mistake I type the following SQL

```
DELETE FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId = 1000
```

and press/hit `EXECUTE`

I would like the trigger to not even allow the delete to succeed.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use an INSTEAD OF delete trigger. https://www.tutorialgateway.org/instead-of-delete-triggers-in-sql-server/

Comment: Great thanks it worked.

Comment: What exactly is the "by mistake" part in that delete? Do you want to prevent delete statements **completely**? Or do you only want to prevent _some_ delete statements. If the latter, then what distinguishes those from others?